# Magento grid default limit

Tags: magento, grid

In Magento grid When I use $this->setDefaultLimit(200); in grid.php it changes the selected value in pager to 200 but when a user changes it to some other value say 50 , even after refreshing/clearing cache it doesnt set pager value to default 200, it remains 50. Where it is stored and how can it be overridden.

Comment: You want to set the limit on admin interface or on the website?

Comment: its perhaps stored in session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method `setSaveParametersInSession()`

which allows you to disable storing variables in session

Look into `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`

Comment: doesn't it save anything else except pager limits?
How does magento saves selected rows(they remain selected - you can find them by selecting yes from checkbox filter- even after changing pager limits which gets you fresh Ajax content)